# Why the run-time of below codes is different? Please elaborate

Tags: python-3.x

Life, universe and Everything:

CODE 1:

```
n=0
 while(n!=42):
     n=int(input())
     if(n!=42):
         print(n)
```

Execution time:1.02914 sec.

CODE 2:

```
while True:
      n=input()
      if(n=='42'):
          break
      else:
          print(n)
```

Execution time: 1.03233 sec.

CODE 3:

```
for i in range(100000):
    n=int(input())
    if(n!=42):
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

Language: Python 3
Execution time : 1.02542

In the CODE2, we are not converting input into integer, still the code takes more time to execute comparatively.
Also, CODE3 takes least time to execute.
why there is a difference in the execution time of the above codes?

Comment: How many times did you execute the code?

Comment: 10 times for the same set of inputs.